# Wordpress Theme SaleJunction

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes

I am updating Images on the Wordpress Theme SaleJunction features page, I have accessed their "How to" material, however I have been unable to generate an image on the front page:

http://prnt.sc/da8nw6

The site is here:

http://1ad.18f.myftpupload.com

In addition there as in error:

"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas16_data01/28/3674128/html/wp-content/themes/salejunction/lib/shop_loop.php on line 14"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are requested to disable the debugging mode for your WordPress from wp-config.php file.

Kindly check your WordPress directory located on your server and do the above changes.

This will help you to figure it out and resolve the issue(s).

https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress